# Windows Phone 8.1 Development - Get data from a list to populate answers on a page

Tags: c#, list, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm attempting to build a sort of quiz for Windows Phone 8.1 using C# and XAML, and I want to add questions and answers to a list/array, and then on the page each line from that list/array populates the buttons and textblocks on the page.

I originally wanted to do this from a text file instead of a list or array but this seemed a lot more complicated than I first thought.

I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

U have plenty of choices. U can do this using an XML file or SQLite or you can store it in a remote machine and develop and REST API and then consume the same on the Windows Phone app.